# Terraform concat everything in yaml files to an object

Tags: security, terraform

Let's say I have 2 yaml files that contains the settings of security module. I want to read them and combine them both into a variable, ideally an object

security_group_1.yaml

```
description : "description 1"
sg_rule : 
   - { type: "ingress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
   - { type: "egress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
```

ecurity_group_2.yaml

```
description : "description 2"
sg_rule : 
   - { type: "ingress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
   - { type: "egress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
```

I want this output:

```
security_group_1 = { 
  description : "description 1"
  sg_rule : 
   - { type: "ingress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
   - { type: "egress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
  },
security_group_2 = { 
  description : "description 2"
  sg_rule : 
   - { type: "ingress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
   - { type: "egress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
}
```

For example, if I want to get description of security_group_1 I can use
`output['security_group_1']['description']`

Comment: By the way the two yaml files you have shared are not valid yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
locals {
  security_groups = { for f in fileset("${path.module}", "security_group_*.yaml") :
    trimsuffix(f, ".yaml") => yamldecode(file(f))
  }
}
```

this will create a single object which contains one element for each security group yaml file present in the working directory.

You can then access each element like so: `local.security_groups.security_group_1`